# How to offer selection of different type of gift boxes or bags in Prestashop?

Tags: prestashop

In our existing store we offer some gift boxes, gift bags to the customer. These bags and boxes are also sold on the store individually as other products. When customer choses on of this packaging options he/she the cost of the packaging is added to the total. The prices of different gift packaging options are different.

In prestashop there is a default question like "Do you like your product in gift box ? " but this does not fullfill the requirement of chosing different kind of packages ...

We are moving this store to prestashop. We need to find a way to realize this situation in prestashop but I don't know how can I do that. I examined all the possible modules but couldn't find a way yet. Is there anyone who will offer me a way to do this ?

Thank you ...

FERDA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package products like gift bags, gift boxes where in the same category. So I added a link to the products page with a picture of sample packaging options. This link is static and does not change in different products. This link directly goes to the category of gits bags and boxes. I also wrote in text that customers may select from our products for packaging in this link. Below you can see the picture. This is not the best solution but that solved my problem...

[image]